# How to dynamically modify the title of the window about wx.FileDropTarget

Tags: python, class, wxpython

How to dynamically modify the title of the window about wx.FileDropTarget，

That is, when drag and drop files into the window, the window's title is changed.

I know the `SetTitle(os.path.basename(name)` can modify the title， but I do not know the code should be placed where.

help me, thank you！

code is:

```
import wx

class FileDrop(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):

        for name in filenames:
            try:
                file = open(name, 'r')
                text = file.read()
                self.window.WriteText(text)
                file.close()
            except IOError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Error opening file\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()
            except UnicodeDecodeError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Cannot open non ascii files\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()

class DropFile(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = (450, 400))

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        dt = FileDrop(self.text)
        self.text.SetDropTarget(dt)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
DropFile(None, -1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parent window class to `FileDrop` as `self.parent`, and use `self.parent.SetTitle` to set the title. Here's your modified code. I commented my changes.

```
import wx
import os # added this

class FileDrop(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, window, parent): # added parent attribute
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.parent = parent # self.parent makes it available to the whole class

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):

        for name in filenames:
            try:
                file = open(name, 'r')
                text = file.read()
                self.window.WriteText(text)
                self.parent.SetTitle(os.path.basename(name)) # magic happens here
                file.close()
            except IOError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Error opening file\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()
            except UnicodeDecodeError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Cannot open non ascii files\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()


class DropFile(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = (450, 400))

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        dt = FileDrop(self.text, self) # we say parent=self which let's the FileDrop class talk to the DropFile wx.Frame. 
        self.text.SetDropTarget(dt)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
DropFile(None, -1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
import wx,os
class FileDrop(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self,window,frame):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.frame = frame
    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        for name in filenames:
            try:
                f = open(name, 'r')
                text = f.read()
                self.window.WriteText(text)
                self.frame.SetTitle(os.path.basename(name))
                f.close()
            except IOError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Error opening file\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()
            except UnicodeDecodeError, error:
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Cannot open non ascii files\n' + str(error))
                dlg.ShowModal()


class DropFile(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title="", size = (450, 400))

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_RICH2)
        dt = FileDrop(self.text,self)
        self.text.SetDropTarget(dt)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
DropFile(None, -1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: wonder if you realize I posted the answer an hour before this?